# HTML5 canvas, save as image, toDataURL(), create ID

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have this little JavaScript canvas snippet:

```
(function() {
    // Creates a new canvas element and appends it as a child
    // to the parent element, and returns the reference to
    // the newly created canvas element


    function createCanvas(parent, width, height) {
        var canvas = {};
        canvas.node = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.context = canvas.node.getContext('2d');
        canvas.node.width = width || 100;
        canvas.node.height = height || 100;
        parent.appendChild(canvas.node);
        return canvas;
    }

    function init(container, width, height, fillColor) {
        var canvas = createCanvas(container, width, height);
        var ctx = canvas.context;
        // define a custom fillCircle method
        ctx.fillCircle = function(x, y, radius, fillColor) {
            this.fillStyle = fillColor;
            this.beginPath();
            this.moveTo(x, y);
            this.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
            this.fill();
        };
        ctx.clearTo = function(fillColor) {
            ctx.fillStyle = fillColor;
            ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
        };
        ctx.clearTo(fillColor || "#ddd");

        // bind mouse events
        canvas.node.onmousemove = function(e) {
            if (!canvas.isDrawing) {
               return;
            }
            var x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
            var y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
            var radius = 10; // or whatever
            var fillColor = '#ff0000';
            ctx.fillCircle(x, y, radius, fillColor);
        };
        canvas.node.onmousedown = function(e) {
            canvas.isDrawing = true;
        };
        canvas.node.onmouseup = function(e) {
            canvas.isDrawing = false;
        };
    }

    var container = document.getElementById('canvas');
    init(container, 200, 200, '#ddd');

})();
```

Now it takes the div with the `id` of `canvas`, and creates a little HTML5 `canvas` inside it, where the user can basically draw with their mouse. NOW thats nice... but what if I had to save whats inside the canvas with `canvas.toDataURL()`? As far as I know, I would have to take the canvas, and do the `canvas.toDataURL()` to save it to an image. But- that needs an ID right? SOOOO when I created the canvas in the `createCanvas` function, how would I make an `id` accompanying it, so I could do something like `document.getElementById("idofcanvas").toDataURL()` ?

Thank you in advance for your help! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But- that needs an ID right?

It doesn't *need* an ID, but an ID won't hurt (so long as it's actually unique `;-)`). Any method to select a DOM element will work here. If there's only one canvas on the page, this would suffice, for example:

```
var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0];
var imageData = canvas.toDataURL();
```

> When I created the canvas in the createCanvas function, how would I make an id accompanying it?

You'd just set the ID property of the canvas element before returning it. Remember, you need to ensure that this value is unique!

```
function createCanvas(parent, width, height) {
    var canvas = {};
    canvas.node = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.node.id = /* some unique value here */;
    canvas.context = canvas.node.getContext('2d');
    canvas.node.width = width || 100;
    canvas.node.height = height || 100;
    parent.appendChild(canvas.node);
    return canvas;
}
```

Comment: You could contain your search to `document.getElementById('canvas').getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0])` in case there are multiple canvases on the page

Comment: That's true. I didn't notice that the canvases is appended to a `<div id="canvas">`.

Comment: OH I just saw the rest of your answer. :) SO cool! :) Didn't know you could just change the id with `canvas.node.id`! :) Amazing! :) It does make sense though, its just like `canvas.node.style` or  `canvas.node.value` or something. dumb moment for me! :) Thanks so much!

Comment: @user2049022 I'm not convinced you actually need to generate an ID at all. Where in the code do you want to be able to call `canvas.toDataURL()`?

Comment: I'm sorry for my stupidity... But I'm encountering a problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15097068/canvas-html5-javascript-code-not-working-with-canvas-todataurl First time I've ever dealt with canvas.