# Canvas HTML5 JavaScript code not working, with canvas.toDataURL()

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I've failed to get this code working:

```
(function() {
    // Creates a new canvas element and appends it as a child
    // to the parent element, and returns the reference to
    // the newly created canvas element


    function createCanvas(parent, width, height) {
        var canvas = {};
        canvas.node = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.context = canvas.node.getContext('2d');
        canvas.node.width = width || 100;
        canvas.node.height = height || 100;
        parent.appendChild(canvas.node);
        return canvas;
    }

    function init(container, width, height, fillColor) {
        var canvas = createCanvas(container, width, height);
        var ctx = canvas.context;
        // define a custom fillCircle method
        ctx.fillCircle = function(x, y, radius, fillColor) {
            this.fillStyle = fillColor;
            this.beginPath();
            this.moveTo(x, y);
            this.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
            this.fill();
        };
        ctx.clearTo = function(fillColor) {
            ctx.fillStyle = fillColor;
            ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
        };
        ctx.clearTo(fillColor || "#ddd");

        // bind mouse events
        canvas.node.onmousemove = function(e) {
            if (!canvas.isDrawing) {
               return;
            }
            var x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
            var y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
            var radius = 10; // or whatever
            var fillColor = '#ff0000';
            ctx.fillCircle(x, y, radius, fillColor);
        };
        canvas.node.onmousedown = function(e) {
            canvas.isDrawing = true;
        };
        canvas.node.onmouseup = function(e) {
            canvas.isDrawing = false;
        };
    }

    var container = document.getElementById('canvas');
    init(container, 200, 200, '#ddd');

})();

function hi(){
var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas');
var imageData = canvas.toDataURL();
    document.getElementById("his").innerHTML=imageData;
}
```

It's a little JavaScript code, which creates a little canvas in the `div` with the `id` of `canvas`.

And, I'm trying to make the image save, and write to a `div` with the `id` of `his` the saved image. NOW that's where the code stops working... I'd greatly appreciate your help, thanks! :)

Comment: Why do you output the URL as `innerHTML`?

Comment: @bergi I thought that it's URL would be accessible in plain text.

Comment: Yeah, it is, altough you better should use `.textContent` for that.

Comment: Whats `.textContent` ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/1359469/1048572

Comment: Still doesn't work, though... :| http://jsfiddle.net/kneDX/973/ @bregi

Comment: @user2049022 please start reading the error messages in your browser's JavaScript console.

Comment: I read the console on Safari via Firebug lite. Nothing there. @MattBall

Comment: @MattBall AH yes. It says that it cannot find the variable `hi()`, but it's not a variable, it's a function: besides, it's declared! Thank you again for your help. :)

Comment: Don't use Firebug Lite for Safari. You'll find that the built-in dev tools are much nicer. https://developer.apple.com/technologies/safari/developer-tools.html

Comment: Yes, Firebug wasn't returning anything. I then used Safari, and got that variable error. @MattBall

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByTagName) returns a `NodeList`, not a single element. So use

```
function hi(){
    var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0];
    imageData = canvas ? canvas.toDataURL() : "could not find a <canvas> element";
    document.getElementById("his").textContent = imageData;
}
```

Comment: When I do exactly what you had in your example, I get this: http://jsfiddle.net/kneDX/974/

Comment: [Simple example doesn't work on JSFiddle](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5431351/1048572): http://jsfiddle.net/kneDX/976/ Don't forget to check your error console!

Comment: So.. what was the problem? @bergi

Comment: See the answers of the linked question!

Answer (score 1):

Image data URLs belong in image `src` attributes. Images don't have `innerHTML`.

Comment: I thought that it's URL would be accessible in plain text.